# Horizontal accuracy

Tags: gps

I am using an app for altitude. It has GPS, barometric pressure and location based. Each giving slightly different values. However, Horizontal Accuracy (66 feet) and Altitude on Ellipsoide (499 feet) are 2 measures I don't understand. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Horizontal accuracy should be just the same what it is for normal GPS location, so your position can be up to 66 feet wrong (so it's possible you're in fact moved 66 feet North, South-East or any other direction in reality, than on your phone screen). Some location services when calculating altitude take the value from DEM (3D model of earth), so in your case it can check the value a.s.l. 66f next to the place you're actually at. No trouble on lowlands, but in more dynamic terrain you may get very big altitude error - sometimes 66feet away can be 100m below.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: One of your two questions has been answered here. You should ask the other one in a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the answers...perfect. I have the information I need to understand the readings now.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

the altitude on ellipsoide (h) is the vertical distance between your point and the ellipsoid (in your case its probably the WGS84 ellipsoid since you're using a standard GPS), for the horizontal accuracy, I'm sorry I don't know.